# Leaflet - Allow for switching to another base layer at higher than max zoom

Tags: leaflet

I have 2 base layers (`map` and `satellite`) that users can switch between.  The satellite layer's max zoom is higher by 2.  I am using Leaflet's provided `L.control.Layers()` to manage the layers

```
var mapLayer = L.tileLayer('map-tiles.example.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
})

var satelliteLayer = L.tileLayer('satellite-tiles.example.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 20,
})

var baseLayers = {
    'Map': mapLayer,
    'Satellite': satelliteLayer
}

var layerControls = L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
```

If the user zooms to 19 or 20 in satellite view, he will not be able to switch back to the map layer (the radio button is disabled) until he zooms back to 18 or lower.

I want the user to be able to switch to the map layer even on zoom 19 or 20.   And when the user switches to the map layer, the zoom will be set to 18.

Is there some way to achieve this with Leaflet's layer control?  Or do I have to build a custom layer control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some way to achieve this with Leaflet's layer control?

Not with the default behaviour, no. If you check the [relevant portion of the source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/aa91af4749efc08791c62da876883b45a971b418/src/control/Control.Layers.js#L392), you'll see that a `L.Control.Layers` *always* disables checkboxes/radio buttons when the layer is out of its `min`/`maxzoom` range.

> Or do I have to build a custom layer control?

Yes, you can [create your own subclass](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html) of `L.Control.Layers` disabling this functionality, replacing the relevant method with a function that does nothing:

```
L.Control.Layers.NeverDisable = L.Control.Layers.extend({

  _checkDisabledLayers: function(){}

});

var myLayersControl = new L.Control.Layers.NeverDisable(
    baselayers, overlayLayers, options);
myLayersControl.addTo(map);
```

You can check a [working example in this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jCP6zwgcqyiAJTKYsqtA?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up just going into the source code and removing the code in `_checkDisabledLayers` that disables the radio button and it works fine.

Comment: That has the downside of breaking if/when you upgrae the Leaflet files, though. Extending the control doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

An easy workaround to have your `mapLayer` selectionable on zooms 19-20 is to use the Tile Layer [`maxNativeZoom`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#gridlayer-maxnativezoom) option at 18, and increase your `maxZoom` to 20.

Then if you still want to automatically decrease the zoom back to 18 when `mapLayer` is selected, use a listener on map [`"baselayerchange"`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-baselayerchange) event, check the `map.getZoom()` and modify it (`map.setZoom(18)`) if desired.